# Tkinter - How can I extend a label widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

below an image. by default a label widget has 3 blank pixels placed on each side for the padding. my question is, how can I extend this padding just on the right size?

[image]

in my real code, the labels contents can change, so this padding, for example 5 pixel, must be the same for each kind of label.

Here is an example program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

Frame1=Frame(root, background="#ffffff")
Frame1.place(x=16, y=16, width=200, height=150)

Canvas(Frame1, height=1, background="#a0a0a0", highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="white").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky="ew")

TestLabel=ttk.Label(Frame1, text="Ciaoooo", background="green", justify="left")
TestLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="w", padx=(20,20)) # the padding is trasparent! I want it with the same color of the label (green).

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want pixel perfect measurements then put it in a panel and set the size of that. Or just dont use Tkinter and instead use C# Winforms

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that illustrates how you are creating the image. Also, please show what you've already tried. The label widget has documented options for padding, as do the commands `grid` and `pack`.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: ciao Bryan, it's just a label widget from the ttk module. from my point of view it's not necessary give an example, or at least not yet. I already tried to use "padx=(0, 5)" option for the grid geometry manager, but this padding is not visible (it's transparent). I want a padding with the same color of the label background. is it possibile? if my question is so simple, please give me the answer.I already searched on internet and unfortunately I'm not a design expert..

Comment: Without a [mcve] we have no way of knowing it's a ttk label. Code is much more useful than a description of the code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I wrote an example. as I already told you, the padding is transparent, and it's not good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add padding to only one side of a ttk label is to create a new style derived from the default style. In the new style, the `padding` option takes a list of up to four values for the left, top, right, and bottom edges. Giving the value of `5` for just the right side will give you the look that you want.

For example, to create and use a new style named "rpad.TLabel" with 5 pixels of padding only on the right it would look something like this:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("rpad.TLabel", padding=(0,0,5,0))
...
TestLabel=ttk.Label(Frame1, style="rpad.TLabel", ...)
```

The site [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) has some documentation on how the styling engine works.

Comment: even if my question has been closed because of unknown reasons, you gave me the right question in time! thanks you Brayan!